# Create List<Task<IEnumerable<MyData>>> for unit test

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, moq

I want to test a method that receives a `List<Task<IEnumerable<MyData>>>` as a parameter

```
public async Task<HashSet<Data>> MyMethod(List<Task<IEnumerable<MyData>>> asyncTasks)
```

At one point in the method I want to test, there is the following assignment :

```
var someDetails =  await asyncTasks[i] ;
```

My scenario is that in the test I create a list of MyData that I want to test, but I need that to appear to be a result of the line above.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You can create tasks from some result value with: `return Task.FromResult(someResultObject);`. Would that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do this step by step.

You say you already have a list of MyData:

```
List<MyData> dataList = ...;
```

`List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, so:

```
IEnumerable<MyData> dataEnumerable = dataList;
```

Let's make that a task by creating a simple task which just returns this IEnumerable as a result:

```
Task<IEnumerable<MyData>> task = Task.FromResult(dataEnumerable);
```

Now we'll create a single-element list containing exactly that item:

```
var taskList = new List<Task<IEnumerable<MyData>>>() { task };
```

Voilà, there's your `List<Task<IEnumerable<MyData>>>`.